# ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero. while converting GeoJSON to GeoTIFF in QGIS UI

Tags: qgis, python, raster, geojson

I am trying to generate a B/W Mask of building in a map using the QGIS. so I used convert vector to raster option where the parameters are in the image below

[image: Paramters]

`gdal_rasterize -l Name_Building -burn 1.0 -tr 52726.0 69182.0 -te 361450.0 745417.0706 366876.883 748668.7912 -ot Byte -of GTiff C:/clipped_data/Name_Building.geojson C:/clipped_data/mask.tiff`

But i am getting the error

```
Input parameters:
{ 'BURN' : 1, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTENT' : '361450.000000000,366876.883000000,745417.070600000,748668.791200000 [EPSG:23834]', 'EXTRA' : '', 'FIELD' : '', 'HEIGHT' : 69182, 'INIT' : None, 'INPUT' : 'C:/clipped_data/Name_Building.geojson', 'INVERT' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/clipped_data/mask.tiff', 'UNITS' : 1, 'USE_Z' : False, 'WIDTH' : 52726 }

GDAL command:
gdal_rasterize -l Name_Building -burn 1.0 -tr 52726.0 69182.0 -te 361450.0 745417.0706 366876.883 748668.7912 -ot Byte -of GTiff C:/clipped_data/Name_Building.geojson C:/clipped_data/mask.tiff
GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero. 
ERROR 1: Cannot create C:/clipped_data/mask.tiff
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.54 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/clipped_data/mask.tiff'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' finished
```

now if I change the output raster size units to 'pixels' then there is no error.
But the problem is that the output image is totally blank. Moreover the range of value in the layer shows 255 to 255 (whatever is the fixed value to burn, I expect the range to be 0-255). Yet I am able to see in the layer overview as given below.

[image]

Comment: `366876 - 361450 = 5426 m` and you are trying to fit pixels of `52726 m` inside it, so it wont fit. I dont know if it might be the problem

Comment: You must use reasonable pixel size. Now your data covers less than one pixel. See similar problems that others have had https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=0x0+dataset.